# All variables in $scope undefined in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a very simple website which uses [Angular.js](http://angularjs.org/) to display its content. I started learning it 2 days ago, and following the official tutorial gave no issues at all.

This is my js file:

```
var Site = angular.module('Website', []);

Site.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/home',  {templateUrl: 'parts/home.html', controller: 'RouteController'})  
    .when('/who',   {templateUrl: 'parts/who.html', controller: 'RouteController'})
    .when('/what',  {templateUrl: 'parts/what.html', controller: 'RouteController'})
    .when('/where', {templateUrl: 'parts/where.html', controller: 'RouteController'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
});

function AppController ($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
    // Set the slug for menu active class
    $scope.$on('routeLoaded', function (event, args) {
        console.log(args);
        $scope.slug = args.slug;
    });
}

function RouteController ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams) {
    // Getting the slug from $routeParams
   var slug = $routeParams.slug; 
   var pages = {
      "home": {
        "title": "Samuele Mattiuzzo",
      },

      "who": {
        "title": "All you'll get, won't blog"
      },

      "what": {
       "title": "Shenanigans about this website"
      },

      "where": {
        "title": "Where can you find me on the net?"
      }
    };
    $scope.$emit('routeLoaded', {slug: slug});
    $scope.page = pages[slug];
}
```

As you can see, it's very simple, it just need to return a page title based on the page slug. In the template (where I load my app with `<body ng-controller="AppController">`), inside the `<ng-view>` directive I have one of those partial templates loaded (which is currently working and displaying static content) but I cannot see the content of `{{page.title}}`.

I have `Batarang` enabled on my browser and I'm testing my website with `web-server.js`, but I've read that Batarang has some issues with variables and scopes and always returns undefined, so that's why I added that `console.log` statement. Doesn't matter what I try to print (args, slug or page, obviously in different parts of the js), it's always undefined.

What am I exactly doing wrong here? Thanks all

Comment: what is app controller in this context

Comment: updated, it's just a listener for now. When this works, it will serve the purpose of loading the json where i'm moving my page titles

Comment: could you pls share the fiddle

Comment: The problem with your code is that you are using $routeparams.slug but you have not defined the same in the route if you want to use $routeprams.slug then you should modify your route to "/home/:slug"

Comment: isn't "home" my slug already? That's what I was expecting, at least... Will provide fiddle asap, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your controllers are being associated with your "Site".

I believe if you change your free functions to be associated with Site this should get you on the right track. Also, you can simplify your code slightly since the information you're looking for is contained in the $location and not $routeParams.

```
Site.controller("RouteController", function($scope, $location) {
var slug = $location.path(); 
var pages = {
  "/home": {
    "title": "Samuele Mattiuzzo",
  },

  "/who": {
    "title": "All you'll get, won't blog"
  },

  "/what": {
   "title": "Shenanigans about this website"
  },

  "/where": {
    "title": "Where can you find me on the net?"
  }
};
$scope.page = pages[slug];
});
```

Additionally, in your AppController you can watch for $routeChangeSuccess instead of notifying on a location change from your RouteController:

```
Site.controller("AppController", function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function() { \\do something }
});
```

Comment: its not mandatory to add controllers to module they can be registered globally